# Python text document similarities (w/o libraries)

Tags: python

I need to create a python program vanilla (without library), which can compute text document similarities between different documents.

The program takes documents as an input and computes a dictionary (matrix) for words of the given input. Each document consists of a sentence and when a new document goes into the program, we need to compare it to the other documents in order to find similar documents. See example below:

Given text input:

```
input_text = ["Why I like music", "Beer and music is my favorite combination",
               "The sun is shining", "How to dance in GTA5", ]
```

The sentences have to be transformed into vectors, see example:

[image]

Hope you can help.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: The problem is, I dont know how to get started as it needs to be put as vectors. And looking through stackoverflow, has not helped much as I haven't found anyone with a similar case.

Comment: Vector is a fancy word. those "lists" that you have over there with zeroes and ones are much more....ah...reasonable to work with.

Comment: "I don't know how to get started" but [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503390/python-text-document-similarities-w-o-libraries#comment93907284_53503913) you say that you've already tried most of the things that the answer lists? If you have tried something already then you *have* started and you should post that code in the question (in future questions.)

Comment: JJJ, the reason I didn't tell you about this is due to the fact that it has nothing to do with vector or matrices, so I thought I was on a wrong track. I would have posted that code if I thought of it as an actual help for you to understand it. Instead I made a table which could ease the explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some ideas:

1. use `new_str = str.upper()` so beer and Beer will be same (if you
   need this)
2. use `list = str.split()` to make a list of the words
   in your string.
3. use `set = set(list)` to get rid of double words
   if needed.
4. start with an empty word_list. Copy the first set in the word_list. In the following steps you can loop over the entries in your set and check if they are part of your word_list.

`for word in set:
        if word not in word_list:
            word_list.append(word)`

5. Now you can make a multi-hot vector from your sentence. (1 if word_list[i] in sentence else 0)
6. Don't forget to make your multi-hot vectors longer (additional zeros) if you add a word to word_list.
7. last step: make a matrix from your vectors.

Comment: Hi tifi90, 

Thank you a lot for your help. We had already tried the first four steps, but the last 3 steps did the trick! Thanks!